# Cómo aplico una función a varias columnas de un dataframe. PYTHON. LIBRERÍA PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

He "generado" un código para que, en función del sexo, la edad y el IMC, me clasifique a una serie de sujetos registrados en un dataframe, al igual que las variables anteriores, como -normal- o -sobrepeso-. Para ello he definido una función, que parece funcionar bien, pero mi problema está en que no consigo aplicársela al dataframe, ya que desconozco el lenguaje y las utilidades de .apply. Les dejo el código a continuación, por si pueden ayudarme. ¿Cómo se aplica una función a varias columnas?

Muchas gracias

````
def SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO(sexo, edad, bmi):
  if sexo=="HOMBRE":
    if edad<=24:
      if bmi<=25.241:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 25<=edad<=34:
      if bmi<=27.1:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 35<=edad<=49:
      if bmi<=28.82:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 50<=edad<=64:
      if bmi<= 29.9:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return"sobrepeso"
    if edad>=65:
      if bmi<=29.83:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
  if sexo =="MUJER":
    if edad<=24:
      if bmi<=23.30:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 25<=edad<=34:
      if bmi<=25.4:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 35<=edad<=49:
      if bmi<=27.8:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 50<=edad<=64:
      if bmi<=32:
        return "normal"
      else: 
        return"sobrepeso"
    if edad>=65:
      if bmi<=30.7:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"

tabla_test= pd.read_csv("datos_test_encuesta_nutricion_kaggle.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(tabla_test)
df['bmi'] = df['bmi'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df["edad"]=df["edad"].astype(int)
df.sexo.apply(func=SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO)
tabla_test["Category"]= tabla_test(["edad"],["bmi"]).apply(EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO) ```
````

Comment: Este no es un foro; es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Haces una pregunta, obtienes respuestas.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Para aplicar una función a varias columnas de un DataFrame, puedes utilizar el método apply() de Pandas. Este método permite aplicar una función a cada una de las filas o columnas de un DataFrame.

En tu caso, lo que debes hacer es llamar a apply() en el DataFrame y pasar como argumento la función que has creado.

```
# Importamos pandas
import pandas as pd

# Definimos la función que clasifica a una persona como "normal" o "sobrepeso"
# en función de su sexo, edad y índice de masa corporal (IMC)
def SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO(row):
  sexo = row["sexo"]
  edad = row["edad"]
  bmi = row["bmi"]
  
  if sexo=="HOMBRE":
    if edad<=24:
      if bmi<=25.241:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 25<=edad<=34:
      if bmi<=27.1:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 35<=edad<=49:
      if bmi<=28.82:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 50<=edad<=64:
      if bmi<= 29.9:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return"sobrepeso"
    if edad>=65:
      if bmi<=29.83:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
  if sexo =="MUJER":
    if edad<=24:
      if bmi<=23.30:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 25<=edad<=34:
      if bmi<=25.4:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 35<=edad<=49:
      if bmi<=27.8:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"
    if 50<=edad<=64:
      if bmi<=32:
        return "normal"
      else: 
        return"sobrepeso"
    if edad>=65:
      if bmi<=30.7:
        return "normal"
      else:
        return "sobrepeso"

# Leemos el archivo CSV con los datos
tabla_test = pd.read_csv("datos_test_encuesta_nutricion_kaggle.csv")

# Creamos un DataFrame a partir de los datos del archivo CSV
df = pd.DataFrame(tabla_test)

# Convertimos la columna "bmi" a float
df["bmi"] = df["bmi"].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)

# Convertimos la columna "edad" a int
df["edad"] = df["edad"].astype(int)

# Aplicamos la función SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO a cada una de las filas de df

df["Category"] = df.apply(SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO, axis=1)
Mostramos el DataFrame resultante

print(df)
```

En este caso, se lee el archivo CSV con los datos, se crea un DataFrame a partir de esos datos, se convierten las columnas "bmi" y "edad" a float y int, respectivamente, y se aplica la función `SEXO_EDAD_NIVEL_DE_PESO` a cada una de las filas del DataFrame. Finalmente, se muestra el DataFrame resultante, que contendrá una nueva columna llamada "Category" con el resultado de aplicar la función a cada una de las filas.

Espero que esto te ayude. Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: MUCHÍSISISISMAS GRACIAS !!!!!!!!!! DE VERDAD, TE LO AGRADEZCO MUCHISÍSISMO

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda marcar tu pregunta como resuelta. Que tengas un buen día ;)

Comment: Las respuestas _se aceptan_ aquí :) No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta si te ha sido útil @Victor.